# ERROR Configuration database connector anypoint studio

Tags: mule, esb

I'm using mysql in wamp and i'm trying to use database connector in anypoint studio. for the configuration i put Host: localhost, port 3306, User: root, password: ,(empty) and i add mysql driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.jar. and then i get this error:

Test connection failed: Cannot get connection for URL
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mulesoft: Communication link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. the driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Could you post your datasource configuration XML?

Comment: thank you for replying. The problem is solved I had to restart the Wamp thank you again.

Comment: @Rajeun Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved I had to restart the Wamp.